# How to create several ContentType fields in a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, generic-foreign-key, contenttype

My Django model uses a Function model, i.e. a generic function in the company (e.g. : CFO).

In this model, I would like to have a field pointing to the default person who holds the function + another field pointing to a backup person in case of problem. Each of this field should be able to point to various models (both the user model + a model with people who have not signed in yet on the website)

As long as I only point to one model, it is easy :

```
class Function(models.Model):
    function_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  # e.g. CFO
    main_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    backup_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

But if I want each of the two fields to point to different models, I need to use ContentType, like :

```
class Function(models.Model):
    functionname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  # e.g. CFO
    
    #GenericForeignKey:
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

How to have two GenericForeignKeys in one model ? (for the main_user and for the backup_user)?

Thanks a lot for you help, I am confused on how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

`GenericForeginKey` can take 2 positional arguments, first of them is the field name for the `ForeignKey` to the `ContentType`, second one is the field name for the object ID for the generic relation. Given that information, you can construct your generic relations like:

```
class Function(models.Model):
    functionname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  # e.g. CFO

    main_user_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    main_user_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    main_user = GenericForeignKey('main_user_content_type', 'main_user_object_id')

    backup_user_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    backup_user_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    backup_user = GenericForeignKey('backup_user_content_type', 'backup_user_object_id')
```